# Lilypond macro that outputs a \score block

Tags: lilypond

I have the following Lilypond source file consisting of a few blocks of the following form:

```
global = \relative { ... }
Soprano = \relative { ... }
Alto = \relative { ... } % ditto Tenor, Bass

\score { \new StaffGroup <<
  \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Soprano >>
  \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Alto >>
  \new Staff << \clef "G_8" \global \Tenor >>
  \new Staff << \clef "F" \global \Bass >>
>> \layout { } }
```

Obviously the `global`, `Soprano`, `Alto`, `Tenor`, `Bass` definitions change each time, but the `\score` block remains the same.

I want to factor that block in a Scheme macro. However, the simplest definition I tried,

```
#(define (Choral) (ly:make-score #{ \new StaffGroup <<
  \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Soprano >>
  \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Alto >>
  \new Staff << \clef "G_8" \global \Tenor >>
  \new Staff << \clef "F" \global \Bass >>
>> #} ))
```

has the following inconvenients: (1) it must be invoked by `#(Choral)` instead of the more natural `\Choral`, and worse, (2) it produces no output whatsoever. If I try to put a `\layout { }` block in the `(Choral)` definition lilypond produces the following error: `error: syntax error, unexpected \layout`.

Is there a simple way to write a macro that produces a `\score` block with attached `\layout` ?

Comment: Self-answer: just use the `collect-music-for-book` function, defined in `scm/lily-library.scm`; full example:

     `Choral = #(define-music-function (parser location) ()
   (collect-music-for-book parser #{ ... #}) #{ #})`  (the second `#{ #}` is a void-music expression, the first one contains the four-voice SATB as above).

Answer (score 2):

Why a Scheme macro? You can just use \include (it's like pasting the content of a file in the line you put it). So you might use the same score block file:

```
% myScoreBlock.ly file
\score {
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Soprano >>
    \new Staff << \clef "G" \global \Alto >>
    \new Staff << \clef "G_8" \global \Tenor >>
    \new Staff << \clef "F" \global \Bass >>
  >> \layout { }
}
```

to be included in any other file which have the same variables:

```
% example of a piece
\version "2.19.54"

global = { \time 2/4 }
Soprano = \relative { d2 }
Alto = \relative { f2 }
Tenor = \relative { e2 }
Bass = \relative { g2 }

\include "myScoreBlock.ly"
```

Another option to reduce the size of the input is using built-in templates. There's also a [built-in template for SATB scores](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/learning/satb-template).

Comment: Pure Scheme (I just posted a solution) is both much cleaner and faster (maybe significantly so, depending on the filesystem).